# How to "write a predicate which returns the opposite of a literal" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How do I write a predicate that will return the opposite of a literal in Prolog such that if I perform the following queries I get the following answers.

```
?- opposite(+a,L).
L = -a.
?- opposite(-a,L).
L = +a.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply

```
opposite(+(X),-(X)).
opposite(-(X),+(X)).
```

Because the `+` or `-` are not part of the constant (atom) `a`, but an operator preceding it (So `-a` is actually a non-operator expression `-(a)`). So we just need to capture whatever that operator precedes in `X`, and say that `L` is the opposite operator precedes that same `X`.

And so:

```
?- opposite(-a,X).
X = +a.

?- opposite(+a,X).
X = -a.
```